# Nested Anonymous Structs in c11

Tags: clang, c11, anonymous-struct

I'm writing a CHIP-8 interpreter in c11 for fun, and I thought it would be cool to decode the opcodes using anonymous structures.

Ideally I'd have a type where if I have the opcode `opcode_t code = {.bits = 0xABCD}`

it should have the following properties:

```
code.I   == 0xA
code.X   == 0xB
code.Y   == 0xC
code.J   == 0xD
code.NNN == 0xBCD
code.KK  == 0xCD
```

The structure that I came up with is:

```
typedef union
{
    uint16_t bits : 16;
    struct
    {
        uint8_t I : 4;
        union
        {
            uint16_t NNN : 12;
            struct
            {
                uint8_t X : 4;
                union
                {
                    uint8_t KK : 8;
                    struct
                    {
                        uint8_t Y : 4;
                        uint8_t J : 4;
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };
} opcode_t;
```

However, when I run the following code to test my struct

```
opcode_t test_opcode = { .bits = 0xABCD };

printf(
        "I = %x, X = %x, Y = %x, J = %x, NNN = %x, KK = %x \n",
        test_opcode.I,
        test_opcode.X,
        test_opcode.Y,
        test_opcode.J,
        test_opcode.NNN,
        test_opcode.KK
);
```

The output is 
`I = d, X = 0, Y = 0, J = 0, NNN = 0, KK = 0`

I am compiling this code in `Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)`

using the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project (Chip8)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 REQUIRED)

find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR}/src)

add_executable (Chip8 src/main.c src/Chip8State.c)

target_link_libraries(Chip8 ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
```

Why is test_opcode.I == 0xD, and why are the rest of the members 0x0?

I'm assuming it's because I'm using uint8_t when I only need a 4 bit number, but I thought using a bitfield would solve that issue.

Is there a way I can modify my typedef to have the desired properties above?

(I understand I could use masking and bit shifting to get the desired values, I'm just think this syntax would be much nicer)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I changed my CMakeList to have `set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED 11)` instead, as I meant to have a C project not c++, however my code still isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd skip everything called bit-fields, since they are non-standard and non-portable. What will happen when you use bit-fields on 8 or 16 bit stdint.h types, nobody knows. In addition you get padding issues because of the structs. And your code will be endianess-dependent. Overall a bad idea (but of course ok just for hobbyist purposes).

Instead, I would just define the type as:

```
typedef uint16_t opcode_t;
```

And then cook up some access macros:

```
#define I(op) ((op & 0xF000u) >> 12)
#define X(op) ((op & 0x0F00u) >>  8)
#define Y(op) ((op & 0x00F0u) >>  4)
#define NNN(op) (op & 0x0FFFu)
#define KK(op)  (op & 0x00FFu)
```

This will translate to the best possible machine code and is 100% portable even across endianess.

You can even invent some higher level macro for generic access and type safety:

```
#define GET(op, type) _Generic(op, opcode_t: type(op))
```

Full example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef uint16_t opcode_t;

#define I(op) ((op & 0xF000u) >> 12)
#define X(op) ((op & 0x0F00u) >>  8)
#define Y(op) ((op & 0x00F0u) >>  4)
#define NNN(op) (op & 0x0FFFu)
#define KK(op)  (op & 0x00FFu)


#define GET(op, type) _Generic(op, opcode_t: type(op))


int main (void)
{
  opcode_t op = 0xABCD;

  printf("I\t0x%"PRIX16 "\n", GET(op, I));
  printf("X\t0x%"PRIX16 "\n", GET(op, X));
  printf("Y\t0x%"PRIX16 "\n", GET(op, Y));
  printf("NNN\t0x%"PRIX16 "\n", GET(op, NNN));
  printf("KK\t0x%"PRIX16 "\n", GET(op, KK));
}
```

Output:

```
I       0xA
X       0xB
Y       0xC
NNN     0xBCD
KK      0xCD
```

Comment: Thanks! That syntax is nice enough :)

Answer (score 1):

In C++ it is not valid to access the "inactive" members of a union.  See here: [Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior)

So your code invokes undefined behavior in C++, though it would be legal in C.

A simple way to fix it is to `memcpy()` the bytes you need into the correct struct.  You can even use one instance of the union to initialize with a literal, then `memcpy()` it to another instance which you then read from--that satisfies the C++ standard.

Comment: I apologize, I meant c11. My fingers must have gotten ahead of me haha.
Edited my post; however the code as written is not working.

Do I need to do something else to specify that I'm compiling a C project, not c++ in my CMakeLists file?

Thanks for the answer

Comment: I changed my CMakeLists to have `set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED 11)`
instead of set `(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 REQUIRED)`

 but still not working as intended

Comment: I don't know.  You wrote your question clearly stating C++11 in the title, body, and tags.  I give up.